# Append new JSON objects to an array in Polymer

Tags: arrays, polymer-2.x

I am using a REST API to fetch an array of objects in a Polymer 2.0.2 project. The response is something like this:

```
[
   {"name":"John","city":"Mumbai"},
   {"name":"Ron","city":"New York"},
   {"name":"Harry","city":"Lisbon"}
]
```

When the response is received, I set my property named `content` as follows:

```
_contentAjaxResponseHandler(event) {         
   this.set('content', event.detail.response);    
 }
```

This works as long as the REST API is called once.
Now, I want to fetch the next batch when user scrolls to the bottom of the page and add it to the existing data.

So, my question is, what is the best way to append new result to the existing `content` array? Or in other words, **What is the best way to merge 2 arrays in polymer?**

Till now, the only way I can think of is to loop over the new result and call `push` method.Something like this:

```
_contentAjaxResponseHandler(event) {
   let newResponse = event.detail.response;
   newResponse.forEach(function(newObj){
      this.push('content',newObj);
   });
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement the feature like `iron-scroller`? https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-scroll-threshold

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. I tried this component. This component is broken and is not working. There are open issues on its Github Page,specially this one: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-scroll-threshold/issues/23. Since, this component was not working, I started writing my own scroll handler

Comment: Have you tried using `concat` function? https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_concat_array.asp

Comment: `concat` worked for me. I had tried concat,but, was using the `push` method to set the `content` value and that's why it was not working. `Polymer` has `set` method to mutate array.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I was going to make that answer. You already did.

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked for me:

```
_contentAjaxResponseHandler(event) {
   let newResponse = event.detail.response;
   this.set('content',this.content.concat(newResponse));
 }
```